# Can I use a more powerful Webview in android like phonegap webview?

Tags: android, cordova, webview

Can I use a more powerful Webview in android like  phonegap or cordova webview?
Some parts of my app need some web pages but the power of Android webview is not very good.As I also want to use many native code,I don't think it is a good idea to use phonegap instead.So is there any  powerful webview which I can use in my native app?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova and phonegap webviews are both based on the android webview.
If you want an improved webview you can try crosswalk project, it's a chromium based webview and compatible with the phonegap API
https://crosswalk-project.org/